# I want to search for my database instead of string with regex

Tags: php, sql, regex

I have this code to search for hashtags, but this is in a string.

```
<?php
$test = '#1 en #2 als voorbeeld moeten niet werken maar #test, #l33t en #swag #420blazeit wel.';

if (preg_match_all('/(^|\s)(#\w+)/', $test, $arrHashtags) > 0) {
  foreach ($arrHashtags[2] as $strHashtag) {
    if (preg_match('/#\d*[a-z_]+/i', $strHashtag)) {
      $test = str_replace($strHashtag, '<a href="http://twitter.com/'.substr($strHashtag, 1).'">'.$strHashtag.'</a>', $test);
    }
  }
}

echo $test;
?>
```

But instead I want to search for hashtags in a text selected from my database.
For example `echo "<p>".nl2br(htmlentities($row['tekst']))."</p>";`, to search in the text I put in my database.

```
<?php

include_once('connection.class.php');

class ShowOne {

    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->databaseConnection();
    }


    public function showOneItem() {
        $query = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id=:itemid AND geblokkeerd=0');
        $query->bindValue(":itemid", $_GET["item"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if($query->execute()) {
            if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
                while($row = $query->fetch()) {
                    echo "<div class='blog'>";
                    echo "<h2>".htmlentities($row['titel'])."</h2>";

                    echo "<table class='showtable'>";

                    echo "<tr><td>Eigenaar blog: </td><td>".htmlentities($row['author'])."</td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr><td>Geplaatst op: </td><td>".htmlentities($row['geplaatstdate'])."</td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr><td>Laatst geupdate op: </td><td>".htmlentities($row['updatedate'])."</td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr><td>Trefwoorden: </td><td>".htmlentities($row['trefwoorden'])."</td></tr>";

                    echo "</table><br />";

                    if ( !empty( $row['afbeelding'] ) ) {
                        echo '<img src="uploadedafb/'.htmlentities($row['afbeelding']).'"<br /><br />';
                    }

                    echo "<p>".nl2br(htmlentities($row['tekst']))."</p>";   

                    echo "<p>".nl2br(htmlentities($row['tekst']))."</p>"; 

                    echo "<br /><p><a class='linkover' href='index.php'><i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left'></i>Terug naar volledig overzicht</a></p>";
                    if(isSet($_SESSION["userid"])) {
                        if($_SESSION["rank"] > 2) { 
                            echo '<a href="bewerken.php?id='.$row["id"].'"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Bewerken</a>'; 
                        } else if($_SESSION['userid'] == $row['userid']) {
                            echo '<a href="bewerken.php?id='.$row["id"].'"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Bewerken</a>'; 
                        }
                    }

                    /*if($row['userid'] == $_SESSION['userid'] || $_SESSION['rank'] > 1) {
                        echo "Verwijder Blog";
                    }*/

                    echo "</div>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<div class='error'><h3>Let op</h3>Er is geen blog gevonden.</div>";   
            }
        } else {
            echo "<div class='error'><h3>Let op</h3>Er is iets fout gegaan met het ophalen van de blog.</div>";
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: I'm ok with your `first code block`, which is clear, but what about the `2nd block` ? i'm having pain to see what do you want about this ? is this the code you tried to do and it doesn't work ? Can you be more clear about what you want (with example maybe). Maybe the fact that all your texts are in German (right ?) in the `2nd block` makes it hard to understand, maybe you could translate it ? (specially for array keys and `echo`s)

Comment: Basicly I want to search for hashtags in my blog, it works for strings. But the blog text is NOT a string its from my SQL database. I can't figure out how I can search for hashtags with that text.

Comment: I don't get the difference you refer to... When you get a data from a database, it is a string (specially in PHP where there is no type). If you don't get a string ,you get an array which contain (in a certain deepness) the string you wish. You are using `$row` as an array with every column as keys. What is the field you want to parse ? Isn't it in a column of your DB ?

Comment: It is a colomn in my database, still giving me problems on undefiend variables $test for example. Can't figure out how to define them.

Comment: if it is in the column `tekst`, the string you wish must be in your `$row['tekst']`. Isn't it what you want ? What is printed in your `echo "<p>".nl2br(htmlentities($row['tekst']))."</p>";` ? don't you get the string you want to parse ?

Comment: OR, if i understand, you are printing in that `<p>` the text you wanna parse, so what you want is to get the content of the `<p>` to parse it ?

Comment: I want to print echo "<p>".nl2br(htmlentities($row['tekst']))."</p>";  But want to search for hashtags in there...

Comment: so do you want to print `#1 en #2 als voorbeeld moeten niet werken maar #test, #l33t en #swag #420blazeit wel.` in the `<p>`, or do you want to print `<a href="http://twitter.com/1">1</a> en <a href="http://twitter.com/2">2</a> als voorbeeld moeten niet werken maar <a href="http://twitter.com/test">test</a>, <a href="http://twitter.com/l33t>l33t</a> en <a href="http://twitter.com/swag>swag</a> <a href="http://twitter.com/420blazeit>420blazeit</a> wel.` in the `<p> ?

Comment: Do you have some kind of chat we can communicate with?

Comment: ok, i added an answer then, please comment if I misunderstood

Comment: I think you should use \# instead of #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you should do like this :

assuming the text tested is: '#1 en #2 als voorbeeld moeten niet werken maar #test, #l33t en #swag #420blazeit wel.'

replace your `echo "<p>".nl2br(htmlentities($row['tekst']))."</p>";`
with:

```
$test = $row['tekst'];
if (preg_match_all('/(^|\s)(#\w+)/', $test, $arrHashtags) > 0) {
  foreach ($arrHashtags[2] as $strHashtag) {
    if (preg_match('/#\d*[a-z_]+/i', $strHashtag)) {
      $test = str_replace($strHashtag, '<a href="http://twitter.com/'.substr($strHashtag, 1).'">'.$strHashtag.'</a>', $test);
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT : removed htmlentities

```
echo "<p>".nl2br($test)."</p>";
```

Comment: Unexpected if, where do i put it? just replace it?

Comment: There were a typo, a `;` was missing after the first line. I fixed it.

Comment: It echo's this <a href="http://twitter.com/inhoud">#inhoud</a> <a href="http://twitter.com/lol">#lol</a> <a href="http://twitter.com/swag">#swag</a> <a href="http://twitter.com/420blazeit">#420blazeit</a>  It doesn't make a link of it. Which is wierd...

Comment: Strange, it makes the same thing than your first block... If your first block worked, it should work too... can you `echo $row['tekst'];` please ?

Comment: if it doesn't make links, you should remove the `htmlentities` which i think prints for real all tags, which isn't what you want.

Comment: Nice ! You just removed htmlentities ? I'll edit my answer. To rate, you just have to accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using some thing like this using explode and implode because i'm not good in regular expression:

```
<?php 

 $test1="";
    $test= '#1 en #2 als voorbeeld moeten niet werken maar #test, #l33t en #swag #420blazeit wel.';// this string is for example you need to use $row['tekst'] instead of this
//$test = $row['tekst']; //un-comment it for your use
    $arrHashtags=explode('#',$test);
        foreach ($arrHashtags as $strHashtag) {
            if(isset($strHashtag) && strlen($strHashtag) > 0){
            $arrHas=explode(' ',$strHashtag);
            $zero=$arrHas[0];
            unset($arrHas[0]);
                $test1.= '<a href="http://twitter.com/'.$zero.'">'.implode(' ',$arrHas).'</a>';
            }
        }

    echo "<p>".nl2br(htmlentities($test1))."</p>";

    ?>
```

Comment: the only difference (that may, or not be a problem) is that the regex defines accepted characters after the `#`, where your method accepts every characters until next space. The regex only accepts `[a-z]` and `_`, so no `CAPS`, and no `-`. I don't see a way to do such things with explode / implode method... do you ?

Comment: @Random no but still you can use string to identify certain characters and avoid them but it's not a good idea.what exactly i did here  is, getting solution with the easiest way with some certain assumptions.using regular expression is good practice.

Comment: yeah, I agree, regex are greedy, have to avoid them as much as possible